# Fail to create cookies while using ngrok with header rewrite

Tags: session, cookies, webhooks, ngrok

I use docker as my local dev environment and use the `dinghy-http-proxy` which adds a new TLD `.docker` to map request to a `nginx-proxy` container.

My websites are typically reached through an URL like http://devel.domain.com.docker.

I want to use ngrok to develop locally while accessing remote webhooks.

I successfully launched ngrok with the command:

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite devel.domain.com.docker 80
```

I can access the login form of my web application through the address http://randomsubdomain.ngrok.io.

**However, I can't log in because it looks like the cookie session can't be set.**

Indeed, cookies sessions are tried to be set for the domain `devel.domain.com.docker` but as we use `randomsubdomain.ngrok.io` in the browser they are blocked for security reasons.

How can I bypass this problem? Am I missing something in my configuration? Is ngrok the right tool for what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 16):

Asked directly to `ngrok.io` support and got this answer:

> No, you're not missing anything, that's just an unfortunate side effect of rewriting the host header. Host header rewriting only works for some applications because of complications like this (and others that involve javascript and cross-origin, etc). If possible, it's always much better to reconfigure your website to accept the ngrok.io host header.

However, I found a solution by checking if the request contains in the header `x-original-host` the domain `ngrok.io`, and then I alter the session mechanism (in PHP `session_set_cookie_params`) to use the `x-original-host` domain instead.

Comment: wow. thank you for posting this! I just spent 8hrs trying to figure out why my cookies weren't persisting. However, in my situation, I'm using Ruby on Rails and the cookies weren't persisting because I simply didn't specify -host-header=rewrite. Added that and it worked perfectly.

Comment: More insight: I ended up having more trouble getting this to work and realized it did not work in Chrome browser, but did work in Firefox! I asked ngrok about this and Alan said: "yeah, it's a chrome security setting i believe? but i've never looked into the right flag to turn it off.
The right way to make it work in chrome is to change: domain=.ngrok.io to
domain=mydomain.ngrok.io - I realized that I am using Rails and I had an option domain: :all in my cookie settings. I removed this in development environment and it works perfectly now!

Comment: Earlier, ngrok was working for me with `domain: all` setting in session store config in my Rails app. But recently I faced similar issues with ngrok and subdomains. The above comment from @PeterP helped me. I had to now just set the `domain: 'mydomain.ngrok.io'` for my local testing instead of `:all`.

Answer (score 0):

As [mperrin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3024940/mperrin) said you have to alter php cookie session mechanism.

Reading from [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

> Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. 
>   The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script.
>   Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request
>   and before session_start() is called.

The **most** important argument is `$domain` and to make **ngrok** work equally decent you can also use **before** `session_start()` the command `ini_set()` (see [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)): `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'xxx.ngrok.io');`

It also took me hours to resolve for my custom hosting php platform but I knew that my auth subsystem should work under a valid hostname apart from `localhost` so I focused in how the cookies are set from my code.

Such kind of php environment settings should be set early by any decent php framework and that was one of my primary goals when I started building it (in my case I only have to change the value in a json text file at the server).